# Get Request Headers for Urllib2.Request?

Tags: python, urllib2

Is there a way to get the headers from a request created with Urllib2 or to confirm the HTTP headers sent with urllib2.urlopen?

Comment: Check any of the related Qs on the right. There are dozens of duplicates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An easy way to see request (and response headers) is to enable debug output:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
```

You then can see the precise headers sent/recieved:

```
>>> opener.open('http://python.org')
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: python.org\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2011 08:23:35 GMT
header: Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
header: Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jun 2011 19:41:35 GMT
header: ETag: "105800d-486d-4a59d1b6699c0"
header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
header: Content-Length: 18541
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: X-Pad: avoid browser bug
<addinfourl at 140175550177224 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f7d29c3d5d0>>
```

You can also set with the `urllib2.Request` objects headers before making the request (and override the default headers, although won't be present in the headers dict beforehand):

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url='http://python.org')
>>> req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0)')
>>> req.headers
{'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0)'}
```

Comment: Is there any way to see the headers that will be sent before sending the request?  I want to simulate sending the request to get the headers that *would* be sent (without actually sending it).

Comment: Note that if you need to add other processors to `build_opener` you can just pass multiple ones to the `build_opener` function. For example to also include a cookie processor you could do `opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar), urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))`.