# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: JavaScript (jQuery) vs. Python (urllib2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I have a device in my local network with a little server and a REST API. I can't change code on this server (it's a commercial IOT device). Now I'm writing a web server with Flask (Python) and JavaScript. When I try to send an HTTP request to this API via JavaScript (jQuery) I get this error:

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I suspect I get this error because the IOT device web server doesn't include `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` probably. Is that correct?
The weird thing is when I send a request with Python with `urllib2.urlopen(<server endpoint url>).read()` it works and I get a JSON response from the server. How is the `urllib2` get request different that the jQuery get request? Why isn't the server blocking the Python request also since it doesn't allow requests with the localhost origin?

EDIT:

Ok to make this a little less confusing here is my setup:

**Flask Python Script** This Flask Python script is used to create a web server and also to make an API call to the IOT device. The code for the API call is: `urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.99/api/status').read()` and this request works fine and sends a JSON response back.

**Flask Web Server** On the flask web server runs a website called website.html. In this file I want to make an API call to the IOT device using JavaScript. My code to do this is:

```
var request = $.ajax({
              url: "http://192.168.0.99/api/status",
              method: "GET"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, msg) {
    console.log( "Request failed: " + msg );
});
```

When I run this code I get the error message: `Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` back in the console of the browser.

**IOT Device** The IOT device is connected to the router via wifi and hosts a web server running on: http://192.168.0.99

Ok now the question is: Why does the Python request work but not the JavaScript request? Don't they both have `http://localhost` as the origin?

Comment: If it's on your network and you're making the request from another machine you _don't_ want to use `localhost`. That loops back to whatever machine is running the code. Your JS request probably needs to be modified. That's all we can say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: the Flask server I set up runs on localhost:5000 and the IOT device has an IP address in the network (its connected via wifi). So this should not be a problem. I should probably also say that the Python request which is successful in accessing the IOT device's web server runs on the web server I created with Flask (its server side). Also when I enter the API endpoints in the browser directly it also works.

Comment: Your Flask server may run on `localhost`, but based on your description I'm fairly satisfied that the commercial IoT device does _not_. What is `<server endpoint url>` in the example above? Again, please _show us both code snippets_ if you want help. It's probably also a good idea to read [ask].

Comment: Hey chris, ok I edited my question and included the code I used for the API calls. You're entirely correct in assuming the IoT device doesn't run on localhost. I included the IP address of the IoT device. Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't the server blocking the Python request also since it doesn't allow requests with the localhost origin?

The *server* isn't blocking the JavaScript request; your *browser* is. Here is some [relevant information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. For example, [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) follow the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). So, a web application using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) *could only* make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow cross-domain requests.

If you can't modify the headers sent by the server you'll have to work around it.

One option would be to set up a local service that acts as a gateway to the IoT device. For example, since your Flask application *can* access the IoT device you could send an `XMLHttpRequest` to your Flask application and have it query the target device. In this case your Flask application could run on the same machine as your browser or on a different machine as long as it sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks a lot for your response. I already implemented your suggestion and it works fine I just don't get why it works (also I don't even have to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header for it to work). I just asked the questions because I want to understand how this works I can't seem to make any sense of this. Because I used XMLHttpRequest in another JavaScript application to make API calls to another domain and it worked fine....

Comment: Ok this is how I understand it:
XMLHttpRequest can NOT make cross-domain requests unless it is explicitly allowed by the server I'm sending the request to. Is that correct?

Comment: It works without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` because the cross-origin security restriction is implemented _within web browsers_, and only for certain types of requests. Python isn't a web browser. Inspect the other `XMLHttpRequest` that's working in your browser's developer tools. Do you see the access control header coming back from the server?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct. `XMLHttpRequest` follows the same origin policy, which means that web browsers forbid it from loading data from another domain unless that other domain sets appropriate headers.

Comment: Ah ok I see that makes sense, so the web browser puts the "origin" key value pair into the request header? And python doesn't send the origin in the header? Is it possible to display all the request and response headers somehow or do I have to use Wireshark for that?

Comment: The web browser adds an `Origin` header, yes. Python (probably) doesn't as it is not running within the context of another site. You can view your browser's request and response headers via its developer tools. You can see response headers from your Python request if you look at `.info().headers` on the response object, i.e. `urllib2.urlopen(...).info().headers` (note that `read()` is absent here). It looks like you might have to enable debug output to see request headers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6340973/354577.